# Limitar acesso ao aplicativo no google play

Tags: java, android

É possível criar algum critério que impossibilite a atualização da minha aplicação no publicada google play?

Cenário atual:

- Possuo um sistema de força de vendas em Android e um ERP em Desktop que trocam informações.

Acontece que para haver essa comunicação, as versões devem está atualizadas conforme o layout de troca de mensagens. E por este motivo, não posso permitir que a aplicação do android atualize para uma versão mais nova, sem antes atualizar o Desktop.

Comment: Porque não faz a versão Desktop aceitar mais de um protocolo de troca de mensagem (versionando os protocolos)? Senão você vai sempre ter um empasse de qual atualizar primeiro. E mesmo que seja resolvido, e quem não quiser atualizar o app?

Comment: É ai onde está o problema. Pra cada N usuários, as versões desktop podem ser: v1, v2, v3. Jogando a app no google play, todos os usuários poderão baixar a nova versão. Logo não terei como atualizar as desktop a curto prazo. Por isso acredito que, se houvesse um meio de validar a atualização pelo google play resolveria este problema.

Comment: Você não precisa validar, contanto que esteja versionando o protocolo e enviando a versão para o Desktop, basta atualizar o Desktop primeiro com VN maior que o App, mantendo todas as versões. No caso, você pode enviar a versão do protocolo que o app Android usa para o Desktop que usando algum pattern (Strategy ou Factory por exemplo) ele seleciona a implementação relativa aquela versão. Se for assim, não importa quando o usuário atualiza o app, sempre vai ter uma compatibilidade por parte do Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais correto nesse caso é vocÊ colocar na Play um aplicativo que gerencia as versões do seu sistema mobile.

Você deixa esse cara disponível na Play e quando o usuário baixa, esse aplicativo é quem irá verificar se o usuário poderá ou não atualizar para a versão mais nova do seu sistema.

Claro que esses apks do seu sistema devem estar em servidor privado (um servidor seu).

Assim, o aplicativo que está na Play, gerenciador de versões, é quem irá verificar no seu servidor se existe atualizações, mas só deixará instalar se a versão do ERP do usuário que está utilizando a versão mobile estiver de acordo.

Nesse último caso, deve haver uma forma do gerenciador também poder validar essa versão do ERP, dependendo do usuário.

Mas aí, na primeira instalação, ele poderia entrar com os dados de conexão para o servidor da empresa, por exemplo.

Comment: Gostei da ideia, porém.. ao realizar o download pelo .apk (controlador de versões) incluso no google play, suponho que será preciso a intervenção do usuário para dar continuidade a instalação. De qualquer forma, me parece a solução mais plausível. Irei testá-la.

Comment: Você integra com qual ERP, WinThor, Protheus... ?

Comment: Olá Cícero, nenhum deles.. trabalho com ERP próprio.